# Which version of MySQL should I use?

Tags: mysql, upgrade, mysql-5.1

For ages I have been using **MySQL 5.1.37**.

Recently I noticed that this version is no longer supported in repository, so I need to upgrade mysql.

I assume that changing the version should be complicated process with changes in **my.cnf**, and may be with the changes in the code.

Questions

- Which version is the most stable and preferred?
- Which version should I use?

Comment: Use the latest and greatest. Simple.

Comment: If you are looking for "most stable" then pick a stable distro and use the supplied packages (eg Debian). On Windows the latest stable release is 5.5 - there is no reason not to use that as it was released in December 2010. Any major problems would be well known by now.

Comment: I am currently using MySQL-5.5.20 and it is working fine.you can go with it.It is also generally available.

Comment: Besides the latest MySQL 5.1 and 5.5, there's also the latest [MariaDB 5.2](http://downloads.askmonty.org/mariadb/) (latest stable version: 5.2.10, released 2011-12-05).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tend to follow the following rule for existing code-base:

> If it's working fine, there is no need to upgrade unless there's a specific feature you are missing.

InnoDB does get some nice performance boosts in 5.5, but if your current use-case is not seeing any issues with your install, why upgrade?

If you ran some performance tests on a development server that indicates you are getting near your limit, you could try 5.5 to see if that helps any.

For future projects, I would definitely recommend 5.5, however.

Comment: Thanks, moving to 5.5, should I consider changing my.cnf or code with queries?

Comment: I highly recommend reading the changelog for MySQL 5.5 and determining that for your use-case. Read-up on innodb performance tuning, and then come back here if you have a specific issue.

Comment: Sometimes, KISS and If-it-aint-broke-dont-fix-it principles work best for most people. +1 for `unless there's a specific feature you are missing.`

Answer (score 7):

You need to get away from MySQL 5.1 ASAP

MySQL 5.0 Active Support ended on December 31, 2009 - Now in Extended Support Phase
Per the MySQL Support Lifecycle policy, active support for MySQL 5.0 ended on December 31, 2009. MySQL 5.0 is now in the Extended support phase.

Versions have changed rapidly since Oracle stepped in

- [MySQL 5.1.61](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?3,508415,508415#msg-508415) released 2012-01-11
- [MySQL 5.1.60](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?3,499574,499574#msg-499574) released 2011-11-18
- [MySQL 5.1.59](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?3,434447,434447#msg-434447) released 2011-09-16
- [MySQL 5.1.58](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?3,425757,425757#msg-425757) released 2011-07-05
- [MySQL 5.1.37](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?3,274289,274289#msg-274289) released 2009-08-02 ( pretty aged by now )

MySQL 5.1 will soon reach its EOL (End of Life) in terms of Active support and go to Extended support (EOL : TBD). Naturally, that support is commerical. It would not hold my breath for that kind of support for the Community versions.

[MySQL 5.5.20 was just released 2012-01-11](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?3,508414,508414#msg-508414) and [5.5.19 was just a month ago](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?3,505047,505047#msg-505047). As with any upgraded product, always read release notes to see what changes and improvements have come about since the previous stable release.