# Why does Oracle keep working on MySQL 5.1

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.1

2 years ago the first version of Mysql 5.5 was released. What is the reason to continue working on MySQL 5.1 - the current release is Mysql 5.1.62

It looks like there are should be fundamental differences between them. I am confused which version to prefer.

Comment: [related question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/10931/1396)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Oracle are obliged to fix security bugs and updates for MySQL 5.1 until the Premium support period has ended - remember that there are paying customers out there using the product in production.

See [page 13 of this document](http://www.oracle.com/us/support/library/lsp-tech-chart-069290.pdf) for support end dates by MySQL version.

MySQL 5.5 is more than ready for production use & I'd recommend using that for any new projects going forward.