# Steps to upgrade MySQL from version 5.0 to version 5.5

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, upgrade, mysql-5, mysql-5.0

I have been developing under MySQL v5.0 for a while now and need to upgrade to v5.5 to be in step with the hosted production server.

After having searched for precise steps to do this migration, I am still unclear as to how to go ahead.

Can anyone provide a clear list of actions needed to upgrade to version 5.5 ?

Thank you

---

Thank you for these answers.
You are right, I should have given fuller info in my question.
Notably - I am under Windows XP SP3.

Yes I did search through Google beforehand, hence my statement

> "After having searched for precise steps to do this migration, 
>   I am still unclear as to how to go ahead."

To RolandoMySQLDBA : Thanks for the script, but I cannot see how I could adapt it.

Comment: I'm with [Pekka 웃](http://stackoverflow.com/users/187606/pekka) BUT, if you must continue, what platform are you on? A "clear list" is always problematic, since the steps vary by use case.

Comment: How much data do you have ???

Comment: If you want to comment someone's answer, please use 'Add comment' button below the answer you want to comment instead of posting your comment as the answer. Also, I would recommend you to associate your new account on this site with your account on Stackoverflow, so that you can accept one of the questions. To do that, go to your account page (click the link with your name on the top of the page) and click Associate account. Thanks.

Comment: @Jack Douglas also hints that you need to request merging of your duplicate account. See http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge

Answer (score 3):

Step 01 : Run this script to Dump Everything from MySQL 5.0

```
cd /root
MYSQL_CONN="-uroot -p..."
SQLSTMT="SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} WHERE schema_name NOT IN"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} ('information_schema','mysql','performance_schema')"
MYSQL_OPTIONS="--skip-column-names -A"
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} ${MYSQL_OPTIONS} -e"${SQLSTMT}" > /tmp/dblist.txt
DB_OPTIONS="--databases"
for DB in `cat /tmp/dblist.txt` ; do DB_OPTIONS="${DB_OPTIONS} ${DB}"
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="--routines --triggers ${DB_OPTIONS}"
mysqldump ${MYSQL_CONN} ${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} > MySQLData.sql
SQLSTMT="SELECT CONCAT('SHOW GRANTS FOR ''',user,'''"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT}@''',host,''';') FROM mysql.user WHERE user<>''"
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} ${MYSQL_OPTIONS} -e"${SQLSTMT}" > GetGrants.sql
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} ${MYSQL_OPTIONS} < /root/GetGrants.sql | sed 's/$/;/g' > Grants.sql
rm -f GetGrants.sql
```

Step 02 : Backup config file

```
cp /etc/my.cnf /etc/my.cnf.50
```

Step 03 : Backup /var/lib/mysql

```
mv /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql50
```

Step 04 : Uninstall MySQL 5.0

Step 05 : Install MySQL 5.5

Step 06 : `service mysql start`

Step 07 : Login to mysql

```
mysql -uroot
```

Step 08 : At the mysql prompt enter the following:

```
mysql> source /root/Grants.sql
mysql> source /root/MySQLData.sql
```

That's it.

Give it a Try !!!

I have suggested this before : [MySQL upgrade 5.0.88 to latest](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39716/mysql-upgrade-5-0-88-to-latest/39763#39763)

Answer (score -1):

You need to follow the steps described in these documentations:

- [Upgrading from MySQL 5.0 to 5.1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html)
- [Upgrading from MySQL 5.1 to 5.5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html)